# Only update not null fields to Mongodb from Pojo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to update only those fields in mongo document that have values in the POJO. How do I do this?

I have a `User` collection with the following document:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("someId"),
    name: "Foo",
    age: 20,
    gender: "male"

}
```

Now I want to update only the age to 22 so, I have a User pojo with `age = 22` and `_id = ObjectId("someId")`.

I don't want to use `Updates.set("age",22)` because then I'll have to handle every field. The field to be populated may be something other than `age`.

So, I used reflection to make a generic method to get the list of `Update.sets` for the pojo

```
classMembers = User::class.memberProperties


// get hashmap from pojo
val fieldsMap: HashMap<String, Any> = 
    mapper.convertValue(pojo, object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}) ?: 
        throw CustomException( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Could not parse request" )

// get hashmap from default/empty pojo
val defaultMap: HashMap<String, Any> = 
    mapper.convertValue(emptyPojo, object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}) ?: 
        throw CustomException( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Could not parse request" )


for (member in classMembers) {
    val name = member.name
    val value = fieldsMap[name]
    //add to list only if the current value is not null or default and current value is different
    if (value != null && defaultMap[member.name] != value && member.getter.annotations.isNotEmpty()) {
        val field = (member.getter.annotations[0] as BsonProperty).value
        setList.add(Updates.set(field, value))
    }
}
```

This works. But I wanted to know if theres a better way to do it? A default way to do this via mongoClient or mongoTemplate or mongoRepository?